# Problema al pasar props desde API en ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, api

Tengo una situación que no entiendo.
Estoy haciendo una llamada a una `API` de meteorologia:

```
const [datosVientocna, setDatosVientocna] = useState([])


  const urlcnarenal = 
   'https://api.oceandrivers.com:443/v1.0/getWeatherDisplay/cnarenal/?period=latesthour';

const obtenerMeteocna = async () => {
    const api = await fetch(urlcnarenal)
    const datosMeteo = await api.json()
    setDatosVientocna(datosMeteo.LATEST_DATA)
    setTimeout (() => {
      obtenerMeteocna()
    }, 100000)
    console.log(datosMeteo)       
      
     }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerMeteocmsap()
    obtenerMeteocna()
           
  }, [])
```

Al hacer el console.log, me aparece toda la info de la api, que estoy buscando.

Al pasar la info a través del state al componente de React.

```
 <DatosMeteo         
    datosMeteocna = {datosVientocna}
    rotuloscna={rotuloscna}
    />
```

Lo recojo en el componente:

```
    export const DatosMeteo = ({datosMeteocmsap, datosMeteocna, rotuloscmsap, 
   rotuloscna}) => {

    <Fragment >
        <div className='container mt-3'>

    <div className='col'>
                        <div className='card card-block h-100 rounded'>
                            <div className='card-body'>
                            <h5 className="card-title bg-primary rounded">{rotuloscna}</h5>  
                                <h5 className="card-title bg-primary rounded">Condiciones de Viento</h5>  
                                <div className='container'>         
                                    <div className='card-body text-center'>   
                                        <H2Viento> {datosMeteocna.TWS} kn</H2Viento>
                                        <h4>Racha: {datosMeteocna.TWS_GUST} kn</h4>
                                        <h4>Dirección: {datosMeteocna.TWD}º  {degToCard (datosMeteocna.TWD)}</h4>                            
                                    </div>       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        

        </Fragment>
        
     );
}
```

Si hago esta programación funciona perfectamente.
Pero si en lugar de hacer la llamada a la `API` de esta forma lo hago usando:

```
const obtenerMeteocna = async () => {
    const api = await fetch(urlcnarenal)
    const datosMeteo = await api.json()
    setDatosVientocna(datosMeteo.LATEST_DATA)
    setTimeout (() => {
      obtenerMeteocna()
    }, 100000)
    console.log(datosMeteo)       
      
     }
```

Al hacer la busqueda en el componente React, usando:

```
<H2Viento> {datosMeteocna.LATEST_DATA.TWS} kn</H2Viento>
                                    <h4>Racha: {datosMeteocna.LATEST_DATA.TWS_GUST} kn</h4>
                                    <h4>Dirección: {datosMeteocna.LATEST_DATA.TWD}º  {degToCard (datosMeteocna.LATEST_DATA.TWD)}</h4>
```

No me deja extraer los datos......

¿Que puede ser? Gracias

Comment: A qué te refieres con "No me deja extraer los datos......" ? Qué error tienes específicamente?

Comment: Me refería a que me daba un error undefined. Ahora estoy viendo que si aplico un condicional antes if(!datosMeteocmsap) return null; ya no me da el error y con la siguiente carga del useeffect() ya me extrae los datos.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta, y puedes contestarla en una respuesta con tu solución

Comment: Mas allá de la solución es necesario hacer esta pregunta: ¿Por que haces un `setTimeout` y llamas ala misma función de forma recursiva cada 100 segundos?

Comment: El motivo es que al ser una estación meteorológica va dando la intensidad del viento, y la dirección. Para navegar es un tipo de aplicación muy útil.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora estoy viendo que si aplico un condicional antes if(!datosMeteocmsap) return null; ya no me da el error y con la siguiente carga del useeffect() ya me extrae los datos.